# Why is Molar Mass of a gas twice the vapour density?

Tags: gas-laws, molecules, density, ideal-gas

I've seen this relation at a number of places, and I can't get why. A simple Google search doesn't give me a simple answer either.

Also, are there any exceptions/conditions for this relation to be true?

Answer (score 5):

[Vapour density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_density) $(\rho_\mathrm{v})$ of a gas is not the absolute density, such as mass density $m/V$ or number density $N/V$. It is in fact *relative* density, compared to the density of some other, reference gas at the same temperature and pressure:
$$\rho_\mathrm{v} = \frac{\rho}{\rho_\text{ref}}.\tag{1}$$
It is a dimensionless quantity (just a number, without a unit). The choice of the reference gas is arbitrary and should be clearly stated. Usually, either hydrogen $(\ce{H2}),$ oxygen $(\ce{O2}),$ or air is chosen.

If the reference gas is hydrogen $(M(\ce{H2})\approx \pu{2 g mol^-1}),$ and we use the ideal gas approximation $(\rho \propto M),$ we can derive the following relation:
$$\rho_\mathrm{v} = \frac{\rho}{\rho(\ce{H2})} = \frac{M}{M(\ce{H2})} \approx \frac{M_\mathrm r}{2} \implies \boxed{M_\mathrm r \approx 2\,\rho_\mathrm{v}},\tag{2}$$
where $M_\mathrm r$ is the relative molecular mass of gas.

If the reference gas is oxygen, then the relation is $M_\mathrm r \approx 16\,\rho_\mathrm{v}$.

The relationship holds only approximately, and it becomes more wrong as we deviate from the ideal gas conditions (e.g. low pressure, high temperature).

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer, very well written. A couple of nitpicks regarding typesetting and notations. First, using complex abbreviations in math mode is a bad idea: $VD$ reads as $V$ *times* $D.$ A single letter with an index is preferred, like $\rho_\mathrm{v}$. Second, don't leave orphaned braces around math mode, *enclose them too* with `$(…)$`. This way they have appropriate height and won't be left hanging at the EoL (see my edit for examples).

Comment: @andselisk, thank you for your comments and your edit! I do not like abbreviated symbol names either, but I used $VD$ as I couldn't find any other more standard symbol for vapour density, and $VD$ appeared several times online.